# printing encoded map<String, dynamic> doesn't work flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, geolocator

I'm using geolocator package and I'm trying to save my position object locally using sharedpreferences, I have no problem with saving data and fetching it again my only problem is I can't encode my position object correctly, here's my code:

```dart
static Future setPosition(Position position) async {
    final unParsedPosition = jsonEncode(position);
    return await _preferences.setString(
      kPositionKey,
      unParsedPosition,
    );
  }
```

```dart
static Position? getPosition() {
    late final Position? parsedPosition;
    final unParsedPosition = _preferences.getString(
      kPositionKey,
    );
    if (unParsedPosition != null) {
      final positionJSON = jsonDecode(   <------ error here
        unParsedPosition,
      );
      parsedPosition = Position.fromMap(
        positionJSON,
      );
    }
    return parsedPosition;
  }
```

and this is the toJson() fun provided by geolocator package

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'longitude': longitude,
        'latitude': latitude,
        'timestamp': timestamp?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        'accuracy': accuracy,
        'altitude': altitude,
        'floor': floor,
        'heading': heading,
        'speed': speed,
        'speed_accuracy': speedAccuracy,
        'is_mocked': isMocked,
      };
```

and my error happens when decoding I referenced it above in my getPosition fun

```
Unexpected character (at character 2)
{longitude: 31.3327177, latitude: 30.1449082, timestamp: 1659333183536, acc...
 ^
```

when I try to print

```dart
String s = jsonEncode(position);
print(s);
```

this doesn't work (my string not printed nothing happens), I need to know why thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try clearing the preferences. Perhaps the saved string is something you stored at an earlier time where the implementation is wrong. Because the string that it tries to work with doesn't look like json. It should not be possible that that is the result of an jsonEncode

Comment: yup, that's right thank you so much Ivo

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `toJson` needs to return a string. The way you could do that is like this:

```
String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    'longitude': longitude,
    'latitude': latitude,
    'timestamp': timestamp?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'accuracy': accuracy,
    'altitude': altitude,
    'floor': floor,
    'heading': heading,
    'speed': speed,
    'speed_accuracy': speedAccuracy,
    'is_mocked': isMocked,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

my code is working but the problem was that the stored data is not correct so trying to fetch it without updating it will give that error.

I stored it wrong but never update it and I keep fetching it without calling setPosition again, that's it